# Aiohttp session timeout doesn't cancel the request

Tags: python, post, timeout, aiohttp

I have this piece of code where I send a `POST` request and set it a maximum timeout using the `aiohttp` package:

```
from aiohttp import ClientTimeout, ClientSession

response_code = None
timeout = ClientTimeout(total=2)

async with ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
    try:
        async with session.post(
            url="some url", json=post_payload, headers=headers,
        ) as response:
            response_code = response.status
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(err)
```

That part works, however the request appears to not be canceled whenever the timeout and respectively the `except` clause are reached -  I still receive it on the other end, even though an exception has been raised. I would like for the request to automatically be canceled whenever the timeout has been reached. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting the timeout in the request itself? I think `session.post` does take the `timeout` parameter.

Comment: Yes, it can overwrite the `session`-specified timeout, but it still behaves the same way - the request is not canceled.

Comment: Perhaps I should have also mentioned that this is running inside a kafka agent (using the `Faust` library), don't know if this makes much of a difference.

Comment: You can try `asyncio.wait_for` - it cancels the task if it reaches the timeout
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for